# Java combine ImageIcons

Tags: java

I have a small Java program that uses ImageIcons on JLabels to display pictures. I want to take two ImageIcons, combine them into a single ImageIcon, and attach that new Image to the JLabel, so something like:

```
ImageIcon img1 = new ImageIcon("src/inc/img/pic1.png");
ImageIcon img2 = new ImageIcon("src/inc/img/pic2.png");
//combine the two into a new Image
// ? ImageIcon newImg = img1+img2;
```

I am just not sure how to go about this, it just needs to be like I opened the two image files in paint, and copied one on top of the middle of the other (pic2 is about half the size of pic1) Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried this but you should be able to do something like this (to draw them side-by-side)

```
Image image1 = img1.getImage(); 
Image image2  = img2.getImage();
int w = image1.width + image2.width;
int h = Math.max(image1.height, image2.height);
Image image = new BufferedImage(w, h,  TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();
g2.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, null);
g2.drawImage(image2, image1.width, 0, null);
g2.dispose();

ImageIcon newImg = new ImageIcon(image);
```

Comment: A few small changes to make the second image centered on the first and it worked perfectly thanks

Answer (score 1):

Got that working with this:

```
    @Test
    public void testIcon() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        File file1 = new File("/etc/alternatives/start-here-32.png");
        File file2 = new File("/etc/alternatives/start-here-24.png");

        BufferedImage img1 = ImageIO.read(file1);
        BufferedImage img2 = ImageIO.read(file2);

        img1.getGraphics().drawImage(img2, 0, 0, img2.getWidth(null), img2.getHeight(null), 0, 0, img2.getWidth(null), img2.getHeight(null), null);
        showImage(img1);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
```

Here is the showImage method:

```
     public void showImage(final BufferedImage image) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel imagePanel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paint(java.awt.Graphics g) {
                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null);

            };
        };

        frame.getContentPane().add(imagePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth() + 100, image.getHeight() + 100));
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Compound Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/compound-icon/) class provides you with flexibility for combining icons in different ways.